# How do I target the style of an icon in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, icons

I have the following code:

```
<span class="stars">★★☆☆☆   </span>
```

I want to target the empty stars to take on a different color. However, I do not know how to target this.

This doesn't do anything:

```
.glyphicon-glyphicon-star-empty{
    color: gray !important;
}
```

And this changes the color of all stars. Not the empty ones.

```
.entry-content span .stars{
    color:gray;
}
```

How can I change the border color to only the empty stars (the last 3)?
I would like to only use CSS, but if JQuery or JavaScript is necessary, then I'm all ears. (FYI this won't be the only class.) I want to target ALL stars when they are empty.

Comment: You can't. They're all inside a single element and they are not elements themselves.

Comment: you can try string manipulation on this `★` and  this `☆` (.replace())

Answer (score 3):

You can color over them using an absolute positioned pseudo-element (`::before`). Use data-stars attribute to change the number of stars. Add the amount of stars you want to color using [jQuery's `_.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [`Element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

```js
$('span').attr('data-stars', '☆☆☆');
```

```css
.stars {
  position: relative;
}

.stars::before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: red;
  content: attr(data-stars);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="stars">★★☆☆☆</span>
```

Comment: This is very helpful! But there's a weird overlapping effect on my site, even when theres  1,3,4 and 5 full or empty stars.

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid you have to use extra classes. Like the following:

```
<span class="stars"><span class=“star-red”>★</span>☆</span>
```

And then simply add the star-red class to your css.